# Updating the version of sumo

Tags: simulator, sumo

I'm using the SUMO simulator with the version 0.22.0  .
I want to update it to the version 0.25.0  .
How can i do it ?

Thanks for help in advance  . 
Regards,
Sp2016

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: This might help: http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/FAQ#How_do_I_upgrade_SUMO.3F

Comment: I delete the last version and i dowload the 0.25.0.0 .But on 'logithèque' it indicates the version 0.25.0 but by command line  it indicates 0.22.0

Comment: I work on ubuntu not windows

Answer (score 1):

You can update sumo by adding another ppa https://launchpad.net/~sumo/+archive/ubuntu/stable to your system. Depending on your ubuntu version this will install a more up to date sumo version from that repository (currently 0.25.0).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sumo/stable
sudo apt-get update
```

and then (again)

```
sudo apt-get install sumo sumo-tools sumo-doc
```

Source: http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Installing

Comment: i do like u said but the some result , always sumo 0.22.0

Comment: which ubuntu version do you use?

Comment: i use ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Did you try uninstalling everything related to sumo and installing again? What does `dpkg --get-selections | grep sumo` show?